# Grok pattern with this log line

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, logstash, logstash-grok

basically I need to filter out Date - SEVERITY - JAVACLASSNAME - ERROR MESSAGE.

This is working for me..But its just half done.
(?[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3}) %{WORD:Severity}(?:%{GREEDYDATA:msg})

It doesnt show Javaclass..!

Here is the output I get

```html
{
  "Timestamp": [
    [
      "2015-03-03 03:12:16,978"
    ]
  ],
  "Severity": [
    [
      "INFO"
    ]
  ],
  "Error_Message": [
    [
      " [http-bio-16006-exec-71] [XYZ.ABC.JLM.app.task.ERT] [app:/saas reqid:23121221 jsid:* aid:* uid: org: vorg: un:] - Received to update queued for monitorId=54213213JBNJBSJBSJBS, worklow=8u298u2189u312, session=21684216814321"
    ]
  ]
}
```

LOGLINE

```
2015-03-03 03:12:16,978 INFO [http-bio-16006-exec-71] [XYZ.ABC.JLM.app.task.ERT] [app:/saas reqid:23121221 jsid:* aid:* uid: org: vorg: un:] - Received to update queued for monitorId=54213213JBNJBSJBSJBS, worklow=8u298u2189u312, session=21684216814321
```

Comment: And "XYZ.ABC.JLM.app.task.ERT" is the Java class you want to extract?

Comment: Yup...So this is out format of logs..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => [
      "message",
      "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:severity} \[(?<threadname>[^\]]+)\] \[(?<classname>[^\]]+)\] %{GREEDYDATA:message}"
    ]
    overwrite => ["message"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you ...I think this is working..need to check it against all the logs

Comment: Where can i find the definition(regexp) of threadname?

When i use the grok pattern:

MYTOMCAT_LOG %{MYTOMCAT_DATESTAMP:timestamp} - %{JAVACLASS:class} -%{NUMBER:time} [(?[^]]+)] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} - %{JAVALOGMESSAGE:logmessage}

grok parser give me a error:

Error: error parsing regexp: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: (?<

Can you help me?

Comment: I want to match a line like this: 2018-05-07 13:21:15,943 - com.yeepay.g3.utils.config.ConfigDataSource -8694 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO - load dbconf from : /apps/dbconfig/CONFIGDS.properties, It is hard to parse the ThreadName part